# Reemplazar multiples caracteres dentro de un string en PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

tengo el siguiente problema.

Uso PostgreSQL y tengo un string con multiples valores que se repiten. Necesito tomar ese valor y sustituirlo con otro valor de otra tabla.

Ejemplo

> `String cadena = "Se actualizarón ordenes de ejecución, de valores: Tipo de mensaje_1,Posición_3Tipo de mensaje_2,Posición_2Tipo de
>   mensaje_3,Posición_1";`

Lo que necesito es reemplazar todos los caracteres que estan despues del guion bajo "_" por un valor de otra tabla.

ID | VALOR 
1 | Uno 
2 | Dos 
3 | Tres

Para que la cadena quede asi:

> `String cadena = "Se actualizarón ordenes de ejecución, de valores: Tipo de mensaje_Uno,Posición_3Tipo de mensaje_Dos,Posición_2Tipo de
>   mensaje_Tres,Posición_1";`

Eso lo hago en una funcion de PostgreSQL, asi que necesito usar PL/PGSQL. Cabe resaltar que los caracteres que necesito reemplazar pueden aparecer N veces dentro del String.

Alguna ayuda?

Comment: ¿Lo que tienes que reemplazar son solo caracteres individuales o puede ser texto largo?

Comment: Quieres un procedimiento almacenado que reciba una cadena de texto y una tabla diccionario, y devuelva esa cadena con todas las ocurrencias de ID reemplazadas por sus respectivos valores?

Comment: Si, se que postgresql no tiene stored procedures pero estoy pensando en hacer una funcion que reciba la cadena de texto y devueva la misma cadena de texto pero con los ID's reemplazados. el replace creo que no funciona porque no se sabe que id es ni cuantas veces se repite. Me explico?

Comment: @RickNuñez ¿te fue de utilidad la respuesta?

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a la documentación oficial de PostgreSQL (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html), se hace de la siguiente manera:

Ejemplo:

```
replace('abcdefabcdef', 'cd', 'XX')
```

Resultado:

```
abXXefabXXef
```

Entonces, vamos por partes:

Reemplazamos todos los 1:

```
replace('Se actualizarón ordenes de ejecución, de valores: Tipo de mensaje_1,Posición_3Tipo de mensaje_2,Posición_2Tipo de mensaje_3,Posición_1','1','Uno')
```

Todos los 2:

```
replace('Se actualizarón ordenes de ejecución, de valores: Tipo de mensaje_1,Posición_3Tipo de mensaje_2,Posición_2Tipo de mensaje_3,Posición_1','2','Dos')
```

Todos los 3:

```
replace('Se actualizarón ordenes de ejecución, de valores: Tipo de mensaje_1,Posición_3Tipo de mensaje_2,Posición_2Tipo de mensaje_3,Posición_1','3','Tres')
```